# i want to create column in bootstrap with Pull and Push but not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, push, pull

## my bootstrap column for big screen is like :-

![i like this type column][for big screen]

Image 1:  ![i like this type column][need reputation to post image]

and I want to this type of image for mobile screen.

![see the image][please solve this query.]

Image 2: ![see the image][I am new member.]

Comment: Please add relative html markup. The question is not clear since images are not displayed in question

Comment: brother. .. i attached image but not post and error with display ("You Need at least 10 reputation to post image.") . :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten into a habit of not using the push and pull features and just use a column but leave the content of that column empty.

From what I can tell, you are trying to do this.

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- ALL SCREENS WILL SEE THIS (ACCEPT MOBILE)-->
    <div class="row hidden-xs">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="img/image.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- MOBILE SCREENS WILL SHOW THIS -->
    <div class="row visible-xs">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="img/image.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit the rows as necessary.

Comment: thanks. for reply. 

check my Query : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981978/i-create-column-in-bootstrap-with-push-and-pull-but-no-working