# I create column in Bootstrap with push and pull but no working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

### I use this code for big screen and small screen

```
 <div class="col-xs-6  col-lg-2">
  <div>A</div>
 </div>

<div class="col-xs-12  col-lg-8 ">
 <div>B</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-2">
 <div>C</div>
</div>
```

### Big screen

|____A___|_______B_______|_____c____|

### i want to this small screen

|_________B___________|

|____A____|_____C_____|

### Please provide code for small

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the *pull* and *push* responsive helper classes.

As Bootstrap 3 is a mobile first framework always start with the smallest view. The order of your columns in the smallest view should be the order of the columns in the html, so *B*, *A* and *C*. Set the size to `.col-xs-12` for *B* and `.col-xs-6` for *A* and *C*. Your smallest layout is now perfect.

For the larger layout, I've used *md*, start with fixing the column sizes, as *A*, *B* and *C* should all occur on a single row they should sum up to 12 columns. As *B* should be twice the size of *A* or *C* this leads to a 
`.col-md-6` for *B* and `.col-md-3` for both *A* and *C*. The size of the columns in the large layout is now correct but column *B* and *A* are in the wrong order.

To fix the order you should move column *A* six columns to the left, so add `.col-md-pull-6` to *A*. Column *B* needs to start after column *A*, so move it three columns to the right by adding `.col-md-push-3`.

```css
.box {
  background-color: #f99;
  border: 1px solid #c66;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-3"><div class="box">B</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-md-pull-6"><div class="box">A</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><div class="box">C</div></div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.S.** This method of creating responsive layouts with different column orders works until you have to push or pull a column to another row. As the push and pull classes set the `left` or `right` property of an column that has `position: relative` this will never make a column wrap to another row. If you need this an option is to duplicate the column and its contents and use classes like `visible-xs-block` to show them in the proper layout.

Comment: thanks for help.. it's working on small screen but no with big screen for lg screen. thanks for help. try to another code.

Comment: what's wrong for the `lg` size? the column sizes? in that case you need to change e.g. the `col-md-3` into `col-lg-2` etc. might be a bit tricky for the _push_ and _pull_ classes but it should be doable.

Comment: thnks. brother. after all the try.. finally got answer. from this. :- http://jsfiddle.net/vqzLL55s/1/

Comment: That's a really bad solution as you can solve this using only Bootstrap's classes. Try adding some height to column B to see what's wrong

Comment: why.. brother. but it works.. and i m happy with it .. you also tried to answer. but when i apply your code then change my columns ... sory brother

Comment: dear "ckuijjer" . sorry.. u r correct.. in this height position problem.. today i applied a code and got problem when posted contain.. please help.. Mr  ckuiijer

Comment: Yeah.. Great.. just use your code. it's all work... thenk Man... (y)

Answer (score 0):

It's far from perfect but it does the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/vqzLL55s/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div>A</div>
    </div>
    <div id="divB" class="col-xs-6">
        <div>B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div>C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry.. brother. when i applied contain in Div - B.. then got problem with hieght.. how to fix it..